# When should you escape strings used in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string

I'm fairly new to PHP but have been familiar with StackOverflow for a while.

I have recently been reading about appropriate times to use mysql_real_escape_string and would appreciate any advice on the following.

Is using mysql_real_escape_string once, on the initial $_POST variable enough to secure the string through the script?

For example:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"]);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password"]);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);
$repeat_password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["repeat_password"]);
```

I declare these values before running a bunch of if statements and finally once the if statements are finished I make an INSERT into the mysql database:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, signup_date) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email', CURDATE())") or die(mysql_error());
```

mysql_real_escape_string is not used anywhere else throughout the if statements - is this safe enough for a rookie to use whilst still maintaining some injection protection?

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` is used for escaping text strings

Comment: You should switch to pdo

Comment: hmm. I was under the impression that I had a decent idea of what it did - I guess I need to carry on my studies!

Comment: You shouldn't store the password. If you can't avoid it, salt it with a large random salt, hash it with a decent algorithm that doesn't have large rainbowtables available.

Comment: Very good that you are aware of injection.. But why doesn't the [canonical question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/383793) answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not safe. You should switch to [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: While I agree that prepared statements are better, can you give an example of where his example could possibly fail?

Comment: Aside from the mysqli / pdo endorsement, @user3570991 should not store password in plain text.

Comment: @Mark: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string

Comment: I'm aware of password encryption - I'm just trying to gain an understanding of the more in depth protection on this basic script before I continue to learn more about php

Answer (score 1):

While mysql_real_escape_string() may (currently) protect you from SQL injection its **deprecated** so you should not you the mysql_* functions anyway, in future versions of PHP It will be removed rending your code useless.

**Why drive a bashed up old ford fiesta when you have the keys to a shiny new Lamborghini?**

[**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: NB: One needs to be very careful to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` correctly in order to benefit from the protection it offers.  It's possible to be lulled into a false sense of security.  See [SQL injection that gets around mysql_real_escape_string()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187/623041).

Answer (score 0):

Try a prepared statement:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO users (`username`, `password`, `email`, `signup_date`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param($username,$password,$email,CURDATE());
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Note $con needs to be a string for connecting to your mysql server.